# How to grey out unused cells when they are hidden? 2018 excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have hidden all unused cells. However, the background is all still white making it look like they're not hidden. 
[image: Example]

Comment: What version of Office did you use?

Answer (score 0):

For Excel 2016, it depends on the Office theme. Change it from "White" to "Colorful".

File **>** Options **>** Personalize your copy of Microsoft Office **>** Office Theme

White vs. Colorful
[image: White Theme] [image: Colorful Theme]

Comment: thank you very much however i am using the newest excel - any idea how to do it on here - thank you

Comment: I would look for the same thing on the newer version too. But I cannot tell where exactly to find it.